# Linux mint 18 RTL8190

Tags: linux-mint, wifi-driver

I'm new on linux (never too late)

To do and learn more, I'd like to get access to the Internet by wifi (so '99 I know).

However, it is still impossible to configure my RTL8190

```
$ lspci
03:07.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter
```

I have used [that tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1433401&p=9941361#post9941361)

So, I had to use ndiswrapper

Now I can see this :

```
$ ndiswrapper -l
net819xp : driver installed
device (10EC:8190) present
```

And this

ifconfig

```
enp0s19f2u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9e:15:1f:12:a4:3b  
          inet addr:192.168.42.32  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c4dd:a5ff:6e04:dd61/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67812 errors:11 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:11
          TX packets:38956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:86740119 (86.7 MB)  TX bytes:5057439 (5.0 MB)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5:49:3b:81:3a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:250916 (250.9 KB)  TX bytes:250916 (250.9 KB)
```

But that

```
$ iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s19f2u2  no wireless extensions.
```

My files

/etc/modules

```
ndiswrapper
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

/etc/default/wpasupplicant

```
ENABLED=0
```

/etc/moprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf

```
alias wlan0 ndiswrapper
```

/etc/moprobe.d/blacklist

```
blacklist net819xp
blacklist wl
```

I am quite stuck here....

Does anyone have any idea / knowledge + time + kindness to help a noob ?
(please... help)